# How to change background image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jQuery to change the background image of a page. At the moment I am using two different buttons which switch the image from Image A to Image B.  Image A is shown by default.

What I would like to achieve is to change the image with a single button which changes name when clicked.

So for Image A the button should just say Zoom In and when clicked, Image B is shown in the background but the button will say Zoom Out.

*Apologies if I've not explained it clearly.*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var images = ['image-A.gif'];

   var url = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function(){
    jQuery('#test').css({'background-image': 'url('+url+')','background-size' : 'cover', 'background-position' : '50px 0'});
jQuery('#test').fadeIn(1000);
  }
  img.src = url;


});
  jQuery(function(){

jQuery("#aChange").click(function(){

    jQuery("#test").css("background-image", "url(image-B.gif)");
    jQuery("#test").css("background-position", "50px -100px");
    jQuery("#test").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
    jQuery("#test").css("background-size", "cover");

    return false;
});     

jQuery("#bChange").click(function(){

    jQuery("#test").css("background-image", "url(image-A.gif)");
    jQuery("#test").css("background-position", "50px 0");
    jQuery("#test").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
    jQuery("#test").css("background-size", "cover");

    return false;
});

});
```

Comment: Would you not be better creating 2 classes with all the CSS that you want in then and just add and remove the class using jQuery

Comment: Is there a reason you are randomizing the starting image? If not, you don't need this bit of code: "images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];"

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'm not jQuery savvy at all and my example was a rehash from something else.  It worked fine and swapped the images using two different buttons but as all developers will state there's no one single correct way to achieve what you want.  I guess it's down to using what you feel comfortable with and what's most efficient.  Thanks for the help. All the solutions work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the classes `.image1 { background-image:url("here") }` and `.image2 { background-image:url("here") }` in CSS

then apply one to the background element, you could just toggle between the two like this

```
$('#theButton').click(function(){
    $('#background').toggleClass('image1').toggleClass('image2');
});
```

also, did you know you could have all of those `.css` functions on one "line"?

```
$('.this').css({
    'color':'green',
    'border':'1px solid black',
    'position','absolute'
});
```

You're missing the point of jQuery if you're coding like that

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Have only one button with the id `aChange`.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#aChange').click(function() {
    var text = jQuery('#aChange').val();

    if (text == "Zoom In") {

      jQuery("#test").css("background-image", "url(image-B.gif)");
      jQuery("#test").css("background-position", "50px -100px");
      jQuery("#test").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
      jQuery("#test").css("background-size", "cover");
    } 
    else {
      jQuery("#test").css("background-image", "url(image-A.gif)");
      jQuery("#test").css("background-position", "50px 0");
      jQuery("#test").css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
      jQuery("#test").css("background-size", "cover");

    }
    jQuery('#aChange').val(text == "Zoom In" ? "Zoom Out" : "Zoom In");

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="aChange" type="button" value="Zoom In">
```

Comment: Instead of doing jQuery('#test').css() 4 times, you can also use .css({"style1":"value style 1", "style 2": "value style 2", etc.})

Comment: @Mortaza : Yes, it would be the optimized way. But i'm just answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.Zoom').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('Zoom');
    if($this.hasClass('Zoom')){
        $this.text('Zoom'); 
        $("html").css("background-color","yellow");
    } else {
        $this.text('Zoom Out');
        $("html").css("background-color","green");
    }
});
```

If I understood well, this may help you. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/V4u5X/703/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with minimal jQuery and a bit of CSS. See the following.

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("img2");   
    $(this).text(function(i, text) {
        return text.indexOf("In") !== -1 && "Zoom Out" || "Zoom In";
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/76132000/jpg/_76132132_z3551404-blue_morpho_butterfly-spl.jpg");
    background-position: 50px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

body.img2 {
   background-image: url("http://wallerz.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/4049_butterfly.jpg")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Zoom In</button>
```